# How to change timestamp of SQLITE DB to local timestamp

Tags: sqlite, timestamp

I insert a record into sqlite database a date by current_timestamp. The idea ist, NOT to set the time manually. Now, the thing is, that my date in the database is 5.30 hours after inserting. Any ideas, how to walk around or fix that?

Comment: fix your timezone settings?

Comment: How are you inserting the record into the db?

Answer (score 23):

use :

```
CREATE TABLE table 
( ... 
, yourColumnName DATETIME DEFAULT (DATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'LOCALTIME'))
, ...
);
```

Comment: It is for me. try changing the column name 'timestamp' to something else.

Comment: When I tried a notification comes saying 'The answer has to be edited".So just edit something so that i will have authorization to revoke the downvote.

Comment: Thank you for not downvoting me after my answer helped you. Its really kind of you.

Comment: @AsafK The column name does not matter. Indeed, you need to deleted the previous db file (by uninstalling the app). Otherwise, the new SQL statement cannot be effective.

Answer (score 9):

The timestamp returned by `current_timestamp` is in UTC.

To convert it to your local current time zone, use the [datetime function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn) VALUES(datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime'))
```

Comment: Thanks CL, its helpful.  If i need to use this datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime') in the Create table query how can i do this. I tried using this in SQL query, it throws an error at "(" character [before "current" word].

Comment: How to set local time as default value to a column?

Comment: @Siva by using the above as the DEFAULT value in the table definition.

Comment: If you really want to have a timestamp use:
```SELECT strftime('%s', MyColumn) as timestamp FROM ... ;```